Expand JSON data into separate rows in Azure Synapse?
I have data structured like so, where there is a column of JSON strings. In each of these JSON strings, there are zero or more key/value pairs. A key could have any name, and a value is an array of at least one string
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Name   | Age | JsonCities                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Alice  | 30  | {"TX":["Houston","Dallas"],"AZ":["Phoenix"]}    |
|   Bob    | 45  | {"FL":["Tampa"]}                                |
|   Carol  | 38  | {}                                              |

I need to expand the JSON column so the data is structured as such, with each pair of state and city getting a row. Carol can be excluded because she has no location data, but if that's difficult to include, I can filter out the null values after
------------------------------------
|   Name   | Age | State |  City   |
------------------------------------
|   Alice  | 30  |  TX   | Houston |
|   Alice  | 30  |  TX   | Dallas  |
|   Alice  | 30  |  AZ   | Phoenix |
|   Bob    | 45  |  FL   | Tampa   |

I'm using Microsoft Fabric with Azure SQL Data Warehouse version 12.0.2000.8 and a compatibility_level of 160
How can I accomplish this, whether using OPENJSON or another method?
I've been trying to solve this using OPENJSON but I can't seem to make it work for my situation. When I try following similar questions, like this one, using this code 
Apply OPENJSON to a single column
SELECT T.[Name], T.[Age], JsonData.[key], JsonData.[value]
FROM users T CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (T.JsonCities) AS JsonData

I get this error

Table-valued function 'OPENJSON_DEFAULT' is not supported in this version of Synapse Sql

but I am able to run something simpler like this without error
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('{}')

Update
I've progressed this far, but still stuck
SELECT
    Name,
    Age,
    City,
FROM
    users
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(users.JsonCities)
    WITH (
        cities_array NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.TX' AS JSON
    ) as root_js

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(root_js.cities_array)
    WITH (
        City VARCHAR(50) '$'
    ) as city_names

This has given me a column of cities in the given state, like '$.TX' here, but how can I get all cities and not just those in the specified state?

I am not very familiar with these platforms so I may be mistaken, but when I run this query to check my version
SELECT @@VERSION
it tells me that I have that version of Azure SQL Data Warehouse

For regular SQL Server you would use https://dbfiddle.uk/5SQGxrfC - but if Synapse Analytics only supports OPENJSON with a WITH clause as seems to be implied by your question you may be out of luck

Thank you, now I can at least confirm this method won't work for me and I'll use something else

@shrimp, what did you end up doing? I'm having the exact same issue at the moment.

@BenPap I ended up having to use a notebook and pyspark to parse it out since it couldn't be done in one go with OPENJSON. Making a json schema like this json_schema = MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(StringType())), adding a column with from_json() with that schema to get valid JSON, and then explode() to expand it

@shrimp Thanks! Funny enough, I came to the exact same conclusion and pretty much did the exact same thing!

I agree with @Martin Smith
Synapse supports OPENJSON with a WITH clause
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[  
  {  
    "Order": {  
      "Number":"SO43659",  
      "Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"  
    },  
    "AccountNumber":"AW29825",  
    "Item": {  
      "Price":2024.9940,  
      "Quantity":1  
    }  
  },  
  {  
    "Order": {  
      "Number":"SO43661",  
      "Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"  
    },  
    "AccountNumber":"AW73565",  
    "Item": {  
      "Price":2024.9940,  
      "Quantity":3  
    }  
  }
]'  
   
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              Number   VARCHAR(200)   '$.Order.Number',  
              Date     DATETIME       '$.Order.Date',  
              Customer VARCHAR(200)   '$.AccountNumber',  
              Quantity INT            '$.Item.Quantity',  
              [Order]  NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON  
 )

Results:

Number  Date    Customer    Quantity    Order
SO43659 2011-05-31T00:00:00.0000000 AW29825 1   "{  
      ""Number"":""SO43659"",  
      ""Date"":""2011-05-31T00:00:00""  
    }"
SO43661 2011-06-01T00:00:00.0000000 AW73565 3   "{  
      ""Number"":""SO43661"",  
      ""Date"":""2011-06-01T00:00:00""  
    }"

OPENJSON is a table-valued function that parses JSON text.
OPENJSON provides a rowset view over a JSON document.
Reference: OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)
